# how to import a class in python Pydev console?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I am using pydev to create a python program.

I have one folder with inside 2 files.
The file simulation_study_stability_selection imports the class stable_lasso from the file stable_lasso

Now if I run the python code using the run button of eclipse everything work. 
Instead if I try to run the code using the eclipse console. I obtain an import error.

I obtain the error even if the cwd of the console is the same where the files are.
How can I solve this error?

```
ls
__pycache__/
simulation_stable_lasso.py
simulation_study_stability_selection/
stable_lasso.py
import stable_lasso
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2732, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-11-89a0ba19f70c>", line 1, in <module>
    import stable_lasso
ImportError: No module named 'stable_lasso'
```

EDIT:

this is my folder containing the eclipse project

```
donbeo@donbeo-HP-EliteBook-Folio-9470m:~/Documents/eclipse_shared/pythoncode/HiMean_HiFreq$ ls
__init__.py  simulation_stable_lasso.py            stable_lasso.py
__pycache__  simulation_study_stability_selection
donbeo@donbeo-HP-EliteBook-Folio-9470m:~/Documents/eclipse_shared/pythoncode/HiMean_HiFreq$
```

Comment: Check pydev pythonpath in project properties.

Answer (score 1):

Add third file to the simulation_study_stability_selection (or whatever directory contains stable_lasso.py file) called

```
 __init__.py
```

Comment: It is still not working. I added on the question some details